# Multiple mongoose pre save middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'd like to use multiple pre-save mongoose Middleware for a single schema, is this possible?

Example:

```
var schema = new Schema(..);

schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // do stuff
  next();
});
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // do another thing
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

INDEED i can. I inspected the schema object and found the following property:

```
  callQueue: 
   [ [ 'pre', [Object] ],
     [ 'pre', [Object] ],
     [ 'pre', [Object] ],
     [ 'pre', [Object] ],
     [ 'pre', [Object] ],
     [ 'pre', [Object] ],
     [ 'pre', [Object] ] ],
```