# Mongoose middleware disable(/unhook/delete/remove) created hooks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In an express/mongoose server application, I want to receive a request, then change state to one which can receive another type of request, and when the second request completes successfully I want to respond to the first one.

---

The way I've implemented this is to use a placeholder document in MongoDB, and set a mongoose post save hook upon receiving the first request. This async middleware is a closure which holds a reference to the response from the first request.

The second request modifies this placeholder document with new information from another remote client. Upon saving this, the post save hook gets run, which determines if this is the correct document, and validates the change w.r.t the first request. If that passes, the first response is sent. Otherwise, the hook continues waiting for the correct change, checking all the saves that happen to that schema.

My problem is that even after the correct and accepted changes happen and the response is returned to the first client, the (shell) post-save hook still remains. Now, this does return instantly upon seeing that the response has been sent successfully, but it bothers me that it still exists and gets called for all saves.

This is an application that's meant to run with an anticipated 1k-10k such requests over its lifetime. So unless the application is periodically restarted, we might see a significant slowdown from all the post-save hooks getting called.

---

Now, onto the questions:

1. Is there a better/easier/straightforward architecture to solve this problem?
2. If not, should I be worried about all the shell post-save hooks for this use case?
3. If so, *how do I delete a freaking hook*?

This is a far more infuriating issue than usual with this sort of thing because of the existence of 'remove' hooks. All the search engines fail to actually point me to disabling/deleting/unhooking/removing middleware functions. Nothing in the docs either.

---

The best I can come up with is to use a single-argument middleware function, and then overwrite that function with {} or undefined (or another closure function if we encounter another request-type-1). Is this the only solution? With this, I lose the ability to make and retain responses of multiple request-type-1s.

Answer (score 0):

Found two methods of doing this, one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42072110/1797533) to delete specific entries in the call queue of the schema.

*EDIT: The following doesn't work with Mongoose as of 5.1.5 - removePost isn't defined.*

The other (better) one was found when perusing the [codebase](https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js/tree/31ec571cef0332e21121ee7157e0cf9728572cc3#removing-pres) [used](https://github.com/bnoguchi/hooks-js#removing-pres) to implement hooks.

You can remove a `post` by using

```
Document.post('set', someFn); // Setting it
Document.removePost('set', someFn); // Removing it
```